# New KitchenAid oven browning baked goods unevenly

Tags: baking

Help!  I am very frustrated.  When baking cookies or cakes in our new (less than one month old) double wall oven, it over browns the edges while the center is not brown at all!  I have been baking for 50 years in a wide variety of ovens from basic to high end and I’ve never had this experience before.  This oven cost ~ $4000 installed.  For that amount of money it should bake perfectly.  I have tried different rack positions, convection, conventional, different temperatures etc with the same results.  When I made dinner rolls yesterday I ended up placing foil over the rolls on the edges so the center rolls could brown.  I bake one pan of rolls (per oven) at a time.

I used two different thermometers in each over to check the temperature and they are accurate.  I think this is somehow related to airflow but I don’t know how to fix the problem.  Using convection (with the fan) made no difference. I am going to call customer service but I’m hoping someone here had the same issue and knows what to do.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what you do:

1. Buy a cannister of commercial biscuits in a tube, like Pillsbury.
2. Bake them according to the instructions with no modifications.
3. Call the store/company you bought the oven from and have them come over for a service call.  Show them the unevenly baked biscuits as evidence.

This is a warranty matter, but (at least in the US), major band tube biscuits are what they use to test baking, so you can speed up the service call by having those already done.